# SPARQL over HTTP not executing

Tags: sparql, jena, fuseki

I am using the SOH commands given by apache jena fuseki platform to s-get and s-post and s-query but I am always getting the output as s-get : command not found. What is wrong in this case and how can I make this work?

Comment: can you please describe what *exactly* you're executing from where and on which Jena version?

Comment: "<some command>: not found" is a message from your shell. Make sure the scripts are on the shall PATH and have the execute flag set.